# Position button on a fixed spot in a Panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have got 3 panels next to each other. Each panel looks like this.

Now I would like to position the button on the bottom of the panel on a fixed position. So that when you see the panels next to each other, the buttons will be nicely lined out.

```
<div class="panel panel-default donation-panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
         <h4>Title</h4>
         <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sagittis cursus posuere. Sed pretium fermentum tempus. Aliquam nec vestibulum lacus.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block donation-link-button">Click</a>
    </div> <!-- end panel body -->
</div>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can place the button in `panel-footer`

Comment: @Morpheus If you mention this in A reply ,I will mark it as the correct action. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your button into the `panel-footer` class:

```
<div class="panel panel-default donation-panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
         <h4>Title</h4>
         <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sagittis cursus posuere. Sed pretium fermentum tempus. Aliquam nec vestibulum lacus.</p>
    </div> <!-- end panel body -->
    <div class="panel-footer">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block donation-link-button">Click</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to close your  tag

Your code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block donation-link-button">Click/a>
```

New code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block donation-link-button">Click</a>
```

Comment: thanks for notifying me on his. But that was not the solution. I fixed my code sample in my topic start.